# Existe alguma maneira de configurar a qualidade da imagem, para aumentar a velocidade de carregamento?

Tags: css, html5

Existe alguma maneira de deixar uma determinada imagem, através do CSS, com uma qualidade menor, para aumentar a velocidade de carregamento da página?

Exemplo: Carregar primeiro uma determinada imagem com a qualidade menor, para depois aumentar a qualidade dela quando o usuário passar o mouse?

Comment: Acho que só com CSS seria difícil. Você poderia usar o `hover` pra mostrar uma imagem diferente quando o usuário passasse o mouse, mas **manter** esse imagem depois é que não sei como fazer (do contrário, quando o usuário tirasse o mouse reverteria pra imagem de menor qualidade).

Comment: @mgibsonbr, pensei em algo assim. Acho que o `data` do jQuery ajudaria. Só não estava querendo usar o `timthumb`, mas é uma solução

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/high-dpi/?redirect_from_locale=pt

Comment: Aqui tem mais: http://blog.cloudfour.com/responsive-images-101-part-4-srcset-width-descriptors/

Comment: Obrigado @IvanFerrer pelas informações

Answer (score 3):

Segue um método que funciona:

**CSS**

```
#div_whatever {
   position: whatever;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: whatever whatever; 
   background-image: url(dir/image.jpg);
   /* image.jpg is a low-resolution at 30% quality. */
}

#img_highQuality {
   display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="img_highQuality" src="dir/image.png">
<!-- img.png is a full-resolution image. -->

<div id="div_whatever"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#img_highQuality").off().on("load", function() {
    $("#div_whatever").css({
        "background-image" : "url(dir/image.png)"
    });
});
```

**O que acontece**

1. Uma versão de baixa resolução background carrega rapidamente.
2. Enquanto isso, a versão de resolução superior está carregando como uma imagem escondida.
3. Quando a versão de resolução superior carrega, o jQuery troca as div's com imagens de baixa resolução pelas imagens de alta resolução.

---

**VERSÃO JS**

Esse exemplo serve para quando é necessário mudar muitos elementos.

**CSS:**

```
.hidden {
   display: none;
}

#div_whatever {
   position: whatever;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: whatever whatever; 
   background-image: url(dir/image.jpg);
   /* image.jpg is a low-resolution at 30% quality. */
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div_whatever"></div>
<img id="img_whatever" class="hidden" src="dir/image.png" onload="upgradeImage(this);">
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function upgradeImage(object) {
    var id = object.id;
    var target = "div_" + id.substring(4);

    document.getElementById(target).style.backgroundImage = "url(" + object.src + ")";
}
```

**Fonte**
[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934548/load-a-low-res-background-image-first-then-a-high-res-one)

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a propriedade hover do css, exemplo:

```css
.imagem {
  background: url(imagem-com-baixa-qualidade.jpg);
  }

.imagem:hover {
  background: url(imagem-com-alta-qualidade.jpg);
  }
```